# Is there a way to reset CSS style overrides in Chrome / Edge's devtools?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I debugged some CSS earlier and now that I've made a fix I want to test it but on every refresh, my custom CSS rules are still there. I need to disable them to see if my fix works.

I looked through the devtool options but I didn't find anything. It wasn't much, just changing "overflow:hidden" on one div but I need to make sure there wasn't anything else.

Is there an option in Chrome/Edge to remove all customizations made to the CSS rules in the Elements tab? Or at least not keep them when the page is refreshed?

Comment: Sounds like you have your dev tools configured to automatically apply those changes to the files in a specific folder - https://itnext.io/1-minute-to-become-a-better-developer-2-5db2e35a7c4a